# htaccess 301 redirect by template. from a/b/c to a/c

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I changed the structure on the site.

Previously:

```
example.com/magazine/articles/arcticle-name
            ^^^^^^^^
```

Now:

```
example.com/articles/arcticle-name
```

When user click on old link he sees 404 page. Can u help me create universal RewriteRule for this link. there are a lot of such links, but they are all of the same type.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: is it magazine directory only or here is another?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/magazine/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Requirements:
`ModRewrite` installed and enabled for your `apache`, also have a look at that link:
http://www.webconfs.com/154/301-redirects-how-to-redirect-your-website/